Theorem 8.14 in Apostol's MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS, 2nd ed:
Here is Theorem 8.14 in the book Mathematical Analysis - A Modern Approach to Advanced Calculus by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

Let $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$ be related as in Definition 8.12. Assume that there exists a constant $M > 0$ such that $p(n+1) - p(n) < M$ for all $n$, and assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. Then $\sum a_n$ converges if, and only if, $\sum b_n$ converges, in which case they have the same sum.

Now here is Definition 8.12:

Let $p$ be a function whose domain is the set of positive integers and whose range is a subset of the set of positive integers such that
$$ i) \qquad \qquad  p(n) < p(m),  \qquad \mbox{ if }  n < m. $$
Let $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ be two series related as follows:
$$
b_1 = a_1 + \cdots + a_{p(1)} $$
$$
ii) \qquad \qquad b_{n+1} = a_{p(n)+1} + a_{p(n)+2} + \cdots + a_{p(n+1)} \qquad \mbox{ if } n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots. 
$$
Then we say that $\sum b_n$ is obtained from $\sum a_n$ by inserting parentheses, and that $\sum a_n$ is obtained from $\sum b_n$ by removing parentheses.

And, here is Theorem 8.13:

If $\sum a_n$ converges to $s$, every series $\sum b_n$ obtained from $\sum a_n$ by inserting parentheses also converges to $s$.

Finally, here is Apostol's proof of Theorem 8.14:

If $\sum a_n$ converges, the result follows from Theorem 8.13. [So far so good!] The whole difficulty lies in the converse deduction. [Indeed!] Let
$$
s_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_n, \qquad t_n = b_1 + \cdots + b_n, \qquad t = \lim_{n \to \infty} t_n. 
$$
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and choose $N$ so that $n > N$ implies
$$
\left\lvert t_n - t \right\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \left\lvert a_n \right\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}. 
$$
[OK!] If $n > p(N)$, we can find $m \geq N$ so that $N \leq p(m) \leq n < p(m+1)$. [Why? How? How can we show this to be true?] For such $n$ we have
$$
\begin{align} 
s_n &= a_1 + \cdots + a_{ p(m+1)}  - \left( a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} + \cdots + a_{ p(m+1) }   \right) \\
&= t_{n+1} - \left( a_{n+1 } + a_{n+2 } + \cdots + a_{ p(m+1) }  \right),
\end{align}
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert s_n - t \right\rvert &\leq \left\lvert t_{n+1} - t \right\rvert + \left\lvert a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} + \cdots + a_{p(m+1)}  \right\rvert \\
&\leq \left\lvert t_{n+1} - t \right\rvert + \left\lvert a_{p(m)+1} \right\rvert + \left\lvert a_{p(m)+2} \right\rvert + \cdots + \left\lvert a_{p(m+1)} \right\rvert \\ 
&< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \big( p(m+1) - p(m) \big) \frac{\varepsilon}{2M} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$
This proves that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = t$.

I think I'm clear on each and every detail in the above proof except for the spot therein that I have indicated.
In particular, how to show that the following holds?

Let $n$ be any positive integer $> p(N)$. Then there exists a positive integer $m \geq N$ such that $N \leq p(m) \leq n < p(m+1)$.

PS:
Although an answer has already appeared, here is what I had in mind:
For each positive integer $n$, we have $p(n)$ is also a positive integer. So we have $p(1) \geq 1$.
For any two positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that, we have $p(m) < p(n)$.
Thus we have $1 \leq p(1) < p(2)$, which implies that $p(2) \geq 2$.
If $p(n) \geq n$ for any given positive integer $n$, we have
$$
p(n+1) > p(n) \geq n,
$$
because $n+1 > n$, which implies that $p(n+1) \geq n+1$.
Therefore $p(n) \geq n$ for all positive integers $n$.
From the last result, we also have
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} p(n) = +\infty.
$$
So if $m$ and $n$ are any two positive integers such that $m < n$, then we also have
$$
m < n \leq p(n),
$$
and hence $m < p(n)$.
If $p\left(n_0 \right) \neq n_0$ for some positive integer $n_0$ (i.e. if $p$ is not the identity function), then there exists a smallest positive integer $n_0$ with this property.

Saaqib, what did you try in order to solve your problem?

@Angelo: It is in fact a good question, just because the OP failed to understand the easiest part of the proof of a theorem, it does not mean that there is context missing or lack of details. Often is is the case that one misses the simplest detail in more complex arguments. The OP is showing that he put a lot of care and effort in formulating his question. Your downvotes and vote for closure seem a little heavy handed.

Here is basically the only part of the proof you outlined that you were not able to understand:

If $p:\mathbb{N} \longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is strictly monotone increasing, then for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$, we have the identity
$$
\mathbb{N}\cap \big[ p(N), +\infty \big)=\bigcup^\infty_{m=N}\mathbb{N}\cap \big[ p(m), p(m+1) \big). 
$$

It happens to be the easy part, but sometimes it happens. Here is an argument that I hope clears this out.
Notice that as $p$ is monotone increasing taking positive integer values,  $p(k)\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. Hence, for any integer $n>p(N)$ there are is an integer $k>N$ such that $n<p(k)$. Let $k'$ be the smallest of all integers $k>N$ such that $n<p(k)$. Then $p(k'-1)\leq n<p(k')$. Clearly $N\leq k'-1$ and this concludes the argument.
Here we use the fact that the set of nonnegative integers is well ordered with the canonical order $\leq$.

I think you've only shown that $$
\mathbb{N}\cap \big( p(N), +\infty \big) \subset \bigcup^\infty_{m=N} \big[ \mathbb{N} \cap \big[ p(m), p(m+1) \big) \big]
$$ instead of $$
\mathbb{N}\cap \big( p(N), +\infty \big)=\bigcup^\infty_{m=N}\big[ p(m), p(m+1) \big).
$$ But even this one-way inclusion does our job! Thanks.

@SaaqibMahmood: Actually what I prove is that $\mathbb{N}\cap[p(N),infty)=\bigcup_{m\geq N}\mathbb{N}\cap[p(m),p(m+1))$. The converse  inclusion you are referring to is trivial: $\mathbb{N}\cap[p(m),p(m+1))\subset\mathbb{N}\cap[p(N),\infty($ for all $m\geq N$.
